# Unable to yum install package with repo configured

Tags: yum, rpm

I am trying to install packages but I am not able to find them with yum install while I have them in the mirror.

Here is the content of my /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-OpenShift-Origin36.repo:

```
[centos-openshift-origin36]
name=CentOS OpenShift Origin
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/openshift-origin36/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-PaaS

[centos-openshift-origin36-testing]
name=CentOS OpenShift Origin Testing
baseurl=http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/openshift-origin36/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-PaaS

[centos-openshift-origin36-debuginfo]
name=CentOS OpenShift Origin DebugInfo
baseurl=http://debuginfo.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-PaaS

[centos-openshift-origin36-source]
name=CentOS OpenShift Origin Source
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/paas/Source/openshift-origin36/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-PaaS
```

My gpgkey:

```
$ more /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-PaaS
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)
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=CVSF
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

If we look at the mirror http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/openshift-origin36/ we can see that origin-node is there. However When I am doing:

```
 yum install origin-node
```

I am not able to install it...

How can I do it? I would like as well to install this version   origin-node-3.6.0-1.0.c4dd4cf.x86_64.rpm> How can I specify it?

Thanks

> Edit 1:

I ran:

```
yum clean all
```

And got:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base centos-openshift-origin36 epel extras updates
Cleaning up everything
Maybe you want: rm -rf /var/cache/yum, to also free up space taken by orphaned data from disabled or removed repos
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
```

Then I did:

```
yum update
```

But still same error.

Comment: What error message are you getting when you run the `yum install` command?

Comment: Hello. I am getting: `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
No package origin-node available.
Error: Nothing to do
`

Comment: Did you clean your yum cache after configuring your repo?  `yum clean all`

Comment: I did `ym clean all` and got `Cleaning repos: base centos-openshift-origin36 epel extras updates
Cleaning up everything Maybe you want: rm -rf /var/cache/yum, to also free up space taken by orphaned data from disabled or removed repos
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors`. The I did again yum update and got `Determining fastest mirrors
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
No packages marked for update`. And finally same error

Comment: First thanks for your help !! So it gives me `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
Warning: No matches found for: origin-node
No matches found`

Comment: @Geoffrey `yum clean all` should be enough to clean the yum cache.  Please edit these additional steps you tried and their outputs into your question.

Comment: Post the output of `yum info origin-node`